# Cast a string to Class in java

Tags: java, casting, setter, getter-setter

I am Passing a string to a setter method

```
PostPublication postPublication = new PostPublication();
                    /*
         * Class MessageCont = Class.forName(messageContext
         * .getProperty("MessageContent").toString());
         */
        postPublication
                .setMessageContent((MessageContent_type0) messageContext
                        .getProperty("MessageContent"));
```

The Setter method at PostPublication Class is

```
public void setMessageContent(
            org.openoandm.www.xml.isbm.MessageContent_type0 param) {

        this.localMessageContent = param;

    }
```

Declaration of localMessageContent is

```
protected org.openoandm.www.xml.isbm.MessageContent_type0 localMessageContent;
```

MessageContent_type0 class code

```
/**
 * MessageContent_type0.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis2 version: 1.6.2  Built on : Apr 17, 2012 (05:34:40 IST)
 */


                package org.openoandm.www.xml.isbm;


            /**
            *  MessageContent_type0 bean class
            */
            @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked","unused"})

        public  class MessageContent_type0
        implements org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean{
        /* This type was generated from the piece of schema that had
                name = MessageContent_type0
                Namespace URI = http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/
                Namespace Prefix = ns1
                */


                        /**
                        * field for ExtraElement
                        */


                                    protected org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement localExtraElement ;


                           /**
                           * Auto generated getter method
                           * @return org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement
                           */
                           public  org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement getExtraElement(){
                               return localExtraElement;
                           }



                            /**
                               * Auto generated setter method
                               * @param param ExtraElement
                               */
                               public void setExtraElement(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement param){

                                            this.localExtraElement=param;


                               }




        /**
        *
        * @param parentQName
        * @param factory
        * @return org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement
        */
       public org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement getOMElement (
               final javax.xml.namespace.QName parentQName,
               final org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory factory) throws org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException{



               org.apache.axiom.om.OMDataSource dataSource =
                       new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource(this,parentQName);
               return factory.createOMElement(dataSource,parentQName);

        }

         public void serialize(final javax.xml.namespace.QName parentQName,
                                       javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter)
                                throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException, org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException{
                           serialize(parentQName,xmlWriter,false);
         }

         public void serialize(final javax.xml.namespace.QName parentQName,
                               javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter,
                               boolean serializeType)
            throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException, org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException{




                java.lang.String prefix = null;
                java.lang.String namespace = null;


                    prefix = parentQName.getPrefix();
                    namespace = parentQName.getNamespaceURI();
                    writeStartElement(prefix, namespace, parentQName.getLocalPart(), xmlWriter);

                  if (serializeType){


                   java.lang.String namespacePrefix = registerPrefix(xmlWriter,"http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/");
                   if ((namespacePrefix != null) && (namespacePrefix.trim().length() > 0)){
                       writeAttribute("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","type",
                           namespacePrefix+":MessageContent_type0",
                           xmlWriter);
                   } else {
                       writeAttribute("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","type",
                           "MessageContent_type0",
                           xmlWriter);
                   }


                   }


                            if (localExtraElement != null) {
                                localExtraElement.serialize(xmlWriter);
                            } else {
                               throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException("extraElement cannot be null!!");
                            }

                    xmlWriter.writeEndElement();


        }

        private static java.lang.String generatePrefix(java.lang.String namespace) {
            if(namespace.equals("http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/")){
                return "ns1";
            }
            return org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getUniquePrefix();
        }

        /**
         * Utility method to write an element start tag.
         */
        private void writeStartElement(java.lang.String prefix, java.lang.String namespace, java.lang.String localPart,
                                       javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {
            java.lang.String writerPrefix = xmlWriter.getPrefix(namespace);
            if (writerPrefix != null) {
                xmlWriter.writeStartElement(namespace, localPart);
            } else {
                if (namespace.length() == 0) {
                    prefix = "";
                } else if (prefix == null) {
                    prefix = generatePrefix(namespace);
                }

                xmlWriter.writeStartElement(prefix, localPart, namespace);
                xmlWriter.writeNamespace(prefix, namespace);
                xmlWriter.setPrefix(prefix, namespace);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Util method to write an attribute with the ns prefix
         */
        private void writeAttribute(java.lang.String prefix,java.lang.String namespace,java.lang.String attName,
                                    java.lang.String attValue,javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException{
            if (xmlWriter.getPrefix(namespace) == null) {
                xmlWriter.writeNamespace(prefix, namespace);
                xmlWriter.setPrefix(prefix, namespace);
            }
            xmlWriter.writeAttribute(namespace,attName,attValue);
        }

        /**
         * Util method to write an attribute without the ns prefix
         */
        private void writeAttribute(java.lang.String namespace,java.lang.String attName,
                                    java.lang.String attValue,javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException{
            if (namespace.equals("")) {
                xmlWriter.writeAttribute(attName,attValue);
            } else {
                registerPrefix(xmlWriter, namespace);
                xmlWriter.writeAttribute(namespace,attName,attValue);
            }
        }


           /**
             * Util method to write an attribute without the ns prefix
             */
            private void writeQNameAttribute(java.lang.String namespace, java.lang.String attName,
                                             javax.xml.namespace.QName qname, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {

                java.lang.String attributeNamespace = qname.getNamespaceURI();
                java.lang.String attributePrefix = xmlWriter.getPrefix(attributeNamespace);
                if (attributePrefix == null) {
                    attributePrefix = registerPrefix(xmlWriter, attributeNamespace);
                }
                java.lang.String attributeValue;
                if (attributePrefix.trim().length() > 0) {
                    attributeValue = attributePrefix + ":" + qname.getLocalPart();
                } else {
                    attributeValue = qname.getLocalPart();
                }

                if (namespace.equals("")) {
                    xmlWriter.writeAttribute(attName, attributeValue);
                } else {
                    registerPrefix(xmlWriter, namespace);
                    xmlWriter.writeAttribute(namespace, attName, attributeValue);
                }
            }
        /**
         *  method to handle Qnames
         */

        private void writeQName(javax.xml.namespace.QName qname,
                                javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {
            java.lang.String namespaceURI = qname.getNamespaceURI();
            if (namespaceURI != null) {
                java.lang.String prefix = xmlWriter.getPrefix(namespaceURI);
                if (prefix == null) {
                    prefix = generatePrefix(namespaceURI);
                    xmlWriter.writeNamespace(prefix, namespaceURI);
                    xmlWriter.setPrefix(prefix,namespaceURI);
                }

                if (prefix.trim().length() > 0){
                    xmlWriter.writeCharacters(prefix + ":" + org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(qname));
                } else {
                    // i.e this is the default namespace
                    xmlWriter.writeCharacters(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(qname));
                }

            } else {
                xmlWriter.writeCharacters(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(qname));
            }
        }

        private void writeQNames(javax.xml.namespace.QName[] qnames,
                                 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {

            if (qnames != null) {
                // we have to store this data until last moment since it is not possible to write any
                // namespace data after writing the charactor data
                java.lang.StringBuffer stringToWrite = new java.lang.StringBuffer();
                java.lang.String namespaceURI = null;
                java.lang.String prefix = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < qnames.length; i++) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        stringToWrite.append(" ");
                    }
                    namespaceURI = qnames[i].getNamespaceURI();
                    if (namespaceURI != null) {
                        prefix = xmlWriter.getPrefix(namespaceURI);
                        if ((prefix == null) || (prefix.length() == 0)) {
                            prefix = generatePrefix(namespaceURI);
                            xmlWriter.writeNamespace(prefix, namespaceURI);
                            xmlWriter.setPrefix(prefix,namespaceURI);
                        }

                        if (prefix.trim().length() > 0){
                            stringToWrite.append(prefix).append(":").append(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(qnames[i]));
                        } else {
                            stringToWrite.append(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(qnames[i]));
                        }
                    } else {
                        stringToWrite.append(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(qnames[i]));
                    }
                }
                xmlWriter.writeCharacters(stringToWrite.toString());
            }

        }


        /**
         * Register a namespace prefix
         */
        private java.lang.String registerPrefix(javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter, java.lang.String namespace) throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {
            java.lang.String prefix = xmlWriter.getPrefix(namespace);
            if (prefix == null) {
                prefix = generatePrefix(namespace);
                javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext nsContext = xmlWriter.getNamespaceContext();
                while (true) {
                    java.lang.String uri = nsContext.getNamespaceURI(prefix);
                    if (uri == null || uri.length() == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    prefix = org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getUniquePrefix();
                }
                xmlWriter.writeNamespace(prefix, namespace);
                xmlWriter.setPrefix(prefix, namespace);
            }
            return prefix;
        }



        /**
        * databinding method to get an XML representation of this object
        *
        */
        public javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader getPullParser(javax.xml.namespace.QName qName)
                    throws org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException{



                 java.util.ArrayList elementList = new java.util.ArrayList();
                 java.util.ArrayList attribList = new java.util.ArrayList();


                            if (localExtraElement != null){
                                elementList.add(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.Constants.OM_ELEMENT_KEY);
                                elementList.add(localExtraElement);
                            } else {
                               throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException("extraElement cannot be null!!");
                            }


                return new org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl(qName, elementList.toArray(), attribList.toArray());



        }



     /**
      *  Factory class that keeps the parse method
      */
    public static class Factory{




        /**
        * static method to create the object
        * Precondition:  If this object is an element, the current or next start element starts this object and any intervening reader events are ignorable
        *                If this object is not an element, it is a complex type and the reader is at the event just after the outer start element
        * Postcondition: If this object is an element, the reader is positioned at its end element
        *                If this object is a complex type, the reader is positioned at the end element of its outer element
        */
        public static MessageContent_type0 parse(javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader reader) throws java.lang.Exception{
            MessageContent_type0 object =
                new MessageContent_type0();

            int event;
            java.lang.String nillableValue = null;
            java.lang.String prefix ="";
            java.lang.String namespaceuri ="";
            try {

                while (!reader.isStartElement() && !reader.isEndElement())
                    reader.next();


                if (reader.getAttributeValue("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","type")!=null){
                  java.lang.String fullTypeName = reader.getAttributeValue("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                        "type");
                  if (fullTypeName!=null){
                    java.lang.String nsPrefix = null;
                    if (fullTypeName.indexOf(":") > -1){
                        nsPrefix = fullTypeName.substring(0,fullTypeName.indexOf(":"));
                    }
                    nsPrefix = nsPrefix==null?"":nsPrefix;

                    java.lang.String type = fullTypeName.substring(fullTypeName.indexOf(":")+1);

                            if (!"MessageContent_type0".equals(type)){
                                //find namespace for the prefix
                                java.lang.String nsUri = reader.getNamespaceContext().getNamespaceURI(nsPrefix);
                                return (MessageContent_type0)org.openoandm.www.xml.isbm.ExtensionMapper.getTypeObject(
                                     nsUri,type,reader);
                              }


                  }


                }




                // Note all attributes that were handled. Used to differ normal attributes
                // from anyAttributes.
                java.util.Vector handledAttributes = new java.util.Vector();




                    reader.next();


                                    while (!reader.isStartElement() && !reader.isEndElement()) reader.next();

                                   if (reader.isStartElement()){



                                     //use the QName from the parser as the name for the builder
                                     javax.xml.namespace.QName startQname1 = reader.getName();

                                     // We need to wrap the reader so that it produces a fake START_DOCUMENT event
                                     // this is needed by the builder classes
                                     org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.NamedStaxOMBuilder builder1 =
                                         new org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.NamedStaxOMBuilder(
                                             new org.apache.axis2.util.StreamWrapper(reader),startQname1);
                                     object.setExtraElement(builder1.getOMElement());

                                         reader.next();

                              }  // End of if for expected property start element

                                else{
                                    // A start element we are not expecting indicates an invalid parameter was passed
                                    throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException("Unexpected subelement " + reader.getName());
                                }

                            while (!reader.isStartElement() && !reader.isEndElement())
                                reader.next();

                                if (reader.isStartElement())
                                // A start element we are not expecting indicates a trailing invalid property
                                throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException("Unexpected subelement " + reader.getName());




            } catch (javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException e) {
                throw new java.lang.Exception(e);
            }

            return object;
        }

        }//end of factory class



        }
```

When i am passing data to set the setter method it throws exception as

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openoandm.www.xml.isbm.MessageContent_type0
```

How can i set the setter method by passing string in it?Thanks in advance

Comment: how is localMessageContent declared ?

Comment: construct `MessageContent_type0` from that string

Comment: What is `MessageContent_type0`? You cannot cast an `Object` to arbitrary types, classes need to be in an [inheritance hierarchy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to be able to cast.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn your String into a MessageContent_type0, a simple cast won't do.

No idea what this class is, but maybe there is something like

```
new MessageContent_type0(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not allowed in java. you can either upcast or downcast any object in a inheritance-hierarchy. But can not cast to anything out of the inheritance-hierarchy.

in your case, in type of `localMessageContent` there must be some constructor with `string` param or method like `setMessage(string)`